# Compute the randomness of a sequence of 16-bit integers

Tags: mysql, random, statistics

I want to be able to compute the randomness of a 16-bit integer (id and sport) in the below SQL table.  Does anybody has a good an simple suggestion.

The result ideally should just show how random is the sport and id numbers given a single source IP Address.  The logic can be outside of SQL totally if needed.  Being pure integer with upper limits it should be reasonable fast performance to do this - I would think

```
mysql> select * from packets limit 12;
+---------------------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| stime               | sip       | dip        | sport | dport | in_out | id    |
+---------------------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 26008 |    53 |      1 | 27205 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 19066 |    53 |      1 | 12517 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 |  4262 |    53 |      1 | 17233 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 |   881 |    53 |      1 | 12689 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 31211 |    53 |      1 |  7485 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 14834 |    53 |      1 |  2299 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 15458 |    53 |      1 |  7923 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 |  8192 |    53 |      1 |  8490 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 31909 |    53 |      1 | 30410 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 |  3482 |    53 |      1 |  2602 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 23597 |    53 |      1 |  8713 | 
| 2012-12-28 15:12:54 | 167837969 | 3406501129 | 13165 |    53 |      1 | 22742 | 
+---------------------+-----------+------------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: What is your definition of "randomness"?

Comment: I want the number not to repeat itself or the distance between numbers (row1 and row2) not be identical to other distances (row3 and row2).  I have looked at some examples that just use standard deviation static number that is big enough (say above 18000) - but would like to see more complex mixture of that and say zscores or runup and rundown of values would be ideal.  I thought there would already be some reuseable out there with someone solving a similar problem.  -- Vijay

Comment: I finally found a code that does something similar to this from Niel Provos DNS scanner..
Anybody has an idea how it can be converted to a SQL like query ? 
http://www.monkey.org/~provos/dnspredict.py

Hi functions stddev and mean are easy to calculate using SQL.  But find differences, runtosum in his subroutine if it can be translated to SQL it will be conisdered a great asset.